# how to send form response using java script email

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying the bellow code its working fine by the way, except the email response i need to send the data i am collecting from in `var queryString = $('#myform').serializeArray();` now i want this response to  map into the body of email as in the written code bellow.please guide me if i am wrong, that how i can pass dynamic variable value into email body or to map the response or any thing else because i want to send the email with the data collect from form field

**Javscript code**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#contact-submit").click(function(){
      var queryString = $('#myform').serializeArray();
       $.each(queryString, function(i, field){
       var first_name = "test";
    });
    $("#alert-message").show().fadeOut(2000);

    sendEmail(first_name)
 });
function sendEmail() {

Email.send({

    Host : 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: '587',
    Username : "ssmeediesmaritim@gmail.com",
    Password : "sometext",
    To : 'muhammadarslantoor@gmail.com',
    From : "newworld.elpis.mailer@gmail.com",
    Subject : "Form Record Receipt",
    Body : "<html><h2>Header</h2><strong></strong><br></br><em>Italic</em></html>"
    }).then(
  message => console.log("success")
  );
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) returns an array of *key-value* pairs, not a string. Instead of the `first_name` variable pass the output of the `serializeArray` method to `sendEmail`.

```
$("#contact-submit").click(function(){
  const dataArray = $('#myform').serializeArray();
  $("#alert-message").show().fadeOut(2000);
  sendEmail(dataArray).then(message => {
    console.log("success", message);
  });
});
```

Then inside `sendEmail` create a parameter for the `dataArray` that is being passed so that you can use it inside the `sendEmail` function.

Because the output of the `serializeArray` method is an array you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over the key value pairs in the array and turn each item from

```
{
  name: 'foo', 
  value: 'bar'
}
```

Into a string

```
"foo: bar"
```

And for this example we use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to turn the array into a string and join them with `<br>` tags to create a list style. But you should add your own flavor here to style the list.

Now you have a string which you can concatenate into the body of your email. JavaScript has [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which make injecting variables into strings an easy task.

I'd suggest that you return the Promise created by `Email.send()` and use `then` in the click listener. This way you can handle the logic of *what to do* when an email is send every time you call `sendEmail`. Makes it more dynamic.

```
function sendEmail(dataArray) {
  const dataString = dataArray.map(({name, value}) => `${name}: ${value}`).join('<br>');

  return Email.send({
    Host : 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: '587',
    Username : "ssmeediesmaritim@gmail.com",
    Password : "Encrypt123",
    To : 'muhammadarslantoor@gmail.com',
    From : "newworld.elpis.mailer@gmail.com",
    Subject : "Form Record Receipt",
    Body : `
      <html>
        <body>
          <h2>Header</h2>
          ${dataString}
        </body>
      </html>`
  });
}
```

Comment: may i iterate this using loop

Comment: I don't know what your question means.

Comment: i mean this array have multiple values dataString and this is a object now i want to itterate the values within this object in the email body

Comment: `dataString` is a string, not an object. `data` is an array with objects in it. Each object is the name and value of an input. Right now `data` is turned from an array of objects into a single string which you can use in your email body. The `map` method iterates over every object in the array and returns a string. I think you should try it out.

Comment: okay alright but the code you send its giving an error syntax error

Comment: I've run my answer through some validations and am not getting any errors on my end. Do you have any details on your error?

Comment: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221592/discussion-between-emiel-zuurbier-and-arslan-minko).